# How To Make Makefile with .PHONY Targets that work on Windows (Windows_NT) and Mac (Darwin)

Tags: makefile

So I found a link that shows I should use the following, but perhaps my logic is wrong within the Makefile. I need to use the Makefile for testing purposes to work on both Mac and Windows. The image is fine and the docker container works, I am just trying to make use of the fact that in Linux/Mac `\` can be used to shorten the commands, whereas in Windows you have to use the backtick (`).

Example:

```bash
.PHONY: validate-lookml
validate-lookml:
    UNAME_S=$(shell uname -s)
    ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)
    docker run --rm -it -e LOOKER_BASE_URL=${LOOKER_BASE_URL} \
        -e LOOKER_CLIENTID=${LOOKER_CLIENTID} \
        -e LOOKER_CLIENT_SECRET=${LOOKER_CLIENTSECRET} mirantis/mirantis_spectacles \
        lookml \
        --base-url ${LOOKER_BASE_URL} \
        --client-id ${LOOKER_CLIENTID} \
        --client-secret ${LOOKER_CLIENTSECRET} \
        --project ${PROJECT} \
        --branch ${BRANCH}
    endif
    ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
    docker run --rm -it -e LOOKER_BASE_URL=${LOOKER_BASE_URL} \
        -e LOOKER_CLIENTID=${LOOKER_CLIENTID} \
        -e LOOKER_CLIENT_SECRET=${LOOKER_CLIENTSECRET} mirantis/mirantis_spectacles \
        lookml \
        --base-url ${LOOKER_BASE_URL} \
        --client-id ${LOOKER_CLIENTID} \
        --client-secret ${LOOKER_CLIENTSECRET} \
        --project ${PROJECT} \
        --branch ${BRANCH}
    endif
    ifeq ($(UNAME), Windows_NT)
    docker run --rm -it -e LOOKER_BASE_URL=${LOOKER_BASE_URL} `
        -e LOOKER_CLIENTID=${LOOKER_CLIENTID} `
        -e LOOKER_CLIENT_SECRET=${LOOKER_CLIENTSECRET} mirantis/mirantis_spectacles `
        lookml `
        --base-url ${LOOKER_BASE_URL} `
        --client-id ${LOOKER_CLIENTID} `
        --client-secret ${LOOKER_CLIENTSECRET} `
        --project ${PROJECT} `
        --branch ${BRANCH}
    endif
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work on Windows, and I need my Makefile to support analysts on Windows Laptops:

Error:

```
C:\Users\richa\Git\Mirantis\dataops-looker [main ≡ +0 ~1 -0 !]> make -s validate-lookml
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
Makefile:9: pipe: No error
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
Makefile:12: pipe: No error
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.
Makefile:15: pipe: No error
usage: spectacles lookml [-h] [--config-file CONFIG_FILE] --base-url BASE_URL
                         --client-id CLIENT_ID --client-secret CLIENT_SECRET
                         [--port PORT] [--api-version API_VERSION] [-v]
                         [--log-dir LOG_DIR] [--do-not-track]
                         [--severity {success,info,warning,error,fatal}]
                         --project PROJECT [--branch BRANCH]
                         [--remote-reset | --commit-ref COMMIT_REF | --pin-imports PIN_IMPORTS [PIN_IMPORTS ...]]
spectacles lookml: error: argument --base-url: expected one argument
make: *** [Makefile:40: validate-lookml] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much confusion here.

A makefile consists of lines written in two completely different languages: one is the make language, and the other is the shell.  You cannot send make operations to the shell, and you cannot run (directly) shell commands in make.

Make tells the difference between these two by use of the TAB character.  Lines that are not indented with TAB are parsed by make, and lines that are indented with TAB are given to the shell.  So, in your makefile:

```
validate-lookml:
        UNAME_S=$(shell uname -s)
        ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)
        docker run --rm -it -e LOOKER_BASE_URL=${LOOKER_BASE_URL} \
```

this is not right because the first two indented lines here are *make* commands, and the third is a *shell* command.  You should write this like:

```
UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)

validate-lookml:
ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)
        docker run --rm -it -e LOOKER_BASE_URL=${LOOKER_BASE_URL} \
         ...
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
         ...
```

etc.

But, there is no `uname` command on Windows so when you run this it won't work, that's why you're getting the error *process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname -s, ...) failed.*  If you have GNU make 4.0 or better I recommend that you look at the `MAKE_HOST` variable and use that instead of trying to run `uname`.

Finally, you don't have to worry about the backslash difference, because make will parse all the backslashes and remove them on its own BEFORE it starts the shell.  So just use backslashes to continue all the lines in your recipe and it will work the same way on all different platforms.

Comment: The rules about what is part of a recipe (sent to the shell) and what isn't are _slightly_ more complex than I mention here, but if you follow these rules it will always work.

Comment: Thanks, MadScientist, this really helped me as I didn't think I could do just the backslashes. This really helped me clean up my Makefile, many thanks.